# Symfony 3: No prod or dev logs, Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem

Tags: symfony

I am getting a generic error ("Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem") while logging in. I understand that the reasons could be numerous, but I am getting nothing in the prod logs. How do I get an message in the log files or alternately, how can I debug this? I am testing against my local environment and so have access to everything. I have deleted all cache(s)

Below is my config_prod.yaml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
            level:  info
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:  console
```

Comment: First things I would check are database connection string and passes. Then double check the `User`entity, any changes not migrated to database, or any other error on entity (maybe empty users in your database and make new ones), use doctrine migrations to be sure your entity matches your user table. Then you could try to clear caches. And then I would look into Apache or Nginx, maybe some permissions issue ?

Comment: I did clear the cache. It is probably out of a database change, but my main question is as to why I do not get any logs and if I can debug this.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the logs and with it the reason for the failure once I set the action level in the monolog above to "info":

*action_level: info*

Still, it is quite remarkable that a fatal error disallowing the application from starting is logged by symfony with mere "info" severity.